# django-jenkins ERROR: runTest (django_jenkins.tasks.lettuce_tests.LettuceTestCase)

Tags: testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, lettuce, django-jenkins

I've been working with lettuce for interface testing for the last year and lately I've been trying to use it with [django-jenkins](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins) for continuous integration.

However, I am having problems on executing only the lettuce tests cases I have into the app directory of my Django project.

When I run `python manage.py jenkins` I get the lettuce tests executed and the lettuce.xml file with the execution details created into the reports folder. Although I am getting two errors I don't know why (see the errors at the end of my post).

I've been trying to google it to see if someone else is having the same problem but I couldn't find anything. If anyone has any idea I will appreciate.

I've been following this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/kmmbvnr/home/django-jenkins-tutorial).

You can check the error [here](http://pastebin.com/nxzUqtcy)

[Here](https://github.com/carlosmr12/django-jenkins-lettuce) you can access my code on github.